# Fetching the items from a list with types

Tags: list, data, graph-api

I have a list with items like this one:
[image]

I'm fetching the data with graph `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{tenant}}:/sites/{{siteName}}:/lists/{{listName}}/items?expand=fields`.

This is a chunk of the response:

[image]

The problem here is that I don't know which is the type, I just have the name of the column and its value, so I don't know if "ThePERSONLookupId" is a person or if it is some other type, I just have a number. How can I get the types of each item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the column definitions to see the types.

[List columnDefinitions in a list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[columnDefinition resource type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0)

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns`

Here is a JSON representation of a columnDefinition resource.

```
{
  "columnGroup": "string",
  "description": "description",
  "displayName": "friendly name",
  "enforceUniqueValues": true,
  "hidden": false,
  "id": "string",
  "indexed": true,
  "name": "staticNameForApi",
  "readOnly": false,
  "required": false,
  "boolean": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.booleanColumn" },
  "calculated": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.calculatedColumn" },
  "choice": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.choiceColumn" },
  "currency": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.currencyColumn" },
  "dateTime": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.dateTimeColumn" },
  "defaultValue": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.defaultColumnValue" },
  "geolocation": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.geolocationColumn" },
  "lookup": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.lookupColumn" },
  "number": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.numberColumn" },
  "personOrGroup": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.personOrGroupColumn" },
  "text": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.textColumn" },
  "isDeletable" : false,
  "propagateChanges": false,
  "isReorderable": false,
  "isSealed": false,
  "validation": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.columnValidation" },
  "hyperlinkOrPicture": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.hyperlinkOrPictureColumn" },
  "term": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.termColumn" },
  "sourceContentType": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.contentTypeInfo" },
  "thumbnail": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.thumbnailColumn" },
  "type": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.columnTypes" },
  "contentApprovalStatus": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.contentApprovalStatusColumn" }
}
```

All of the object properties whose type name ends with Column are the possible column types. So if the column is a lookup there will be a lookup property, if it's a choice there will be a choice property, and so on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before but the response is this one:
`{
            "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
            "description": "",
            "displayName": "ID",
            "enforceUniqueValues": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "id": "1d22",
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "ID",
            "readOnly": true,
            "required": false
        },`
I'm using this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{tenant}}:/sites/{{siteName}}:/lists/{{listName}}/columns`. This could be the problem?

Comment: I just checked a couple of my lists and it appears that the column definitions for number columns don't necessarily have a number property. Maybe that's the default column type. I couldn't find any documentation that provides additional information.

Comment: I think this is why I am not getting all the properties.
`Note: These properties correspond to the SharePoint SPFieldType enumeration. Note that the most common field types are represented in the previous table. However, this API is still missing some. In those cases, none of the column type facets will be populated, and the column will only have its basic properties. Sites and list columns response won't contain isDeletable, propagateChanges, isReorderable, isSealed, validation, hyperlinkOrPicture, term, sourceContentType, thumbnail, type, contentApprovalStatus, and sourceColumn properties.`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but probably could be helpful for someone.

You can know the column value type by calling to contentTypes endpoint with `expand` parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contenttype?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{SiteId}}/lists/{{ListName}}/contentTypes?expand=columns
```

It will return JSON with collection of `columns[]` - column objects existing for the list with all properties for each, including `type`, i.e.:

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "\"1\"",
    "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
    "description": "Test Column",
    "displayName": "Test",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "id": "f157d6ae-ef58-4a26-9b46-288cbc4769de",
    "indexed": true,
    "isDeletable": true,
    "isReorderable": true,
    "isSealed": false,
    "propagateChanges": false,
    "name": "Test",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "type": "text",
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": false,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
    },
    "validation": {
        "defaultLanguage": "en-US",
        "descriptions": [
            {
                "languageTag": "en-US"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

`lookup` or `user` column values can be accessed with FieldValueSet resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fieldvalueset?view=graph-rest-1.0). You should just add a `select` parameter to your request to show them explicitly (The response JSON will only contain columns specified in `select` list):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{SiteId}}/lists/{{ListName}}/items/{{ItemId}}?expand=fields(select=MylookuptestLookupId,Mylookuptest,ThePERSONLookupId,ThePERSON)
```

By the way, to update lookup/user column, you'll have to pass `LookupId` value, not plain text.
For `user` they can be retrieved from `User Information List`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{SiteId}}/lists/User Information List/items?expand=fields
```

You may also filter out the results by requesting only Person type and/or user name

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{SiteId}}/lists/User Information List/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/ContentType eq 'Person'
```

For `lookup` - get values from the list associated with the column